# How to Prove a Function is Pretty?

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

Be $C,D > 0 $. We say that a function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is *pretty* if $f$ is of class $C^2$, $|x^3f(x)| \leq C$ and $|xf''(x)| \leq D$, for all $x$ with $|x| \geq 1$.

I want to know how to prove that if a function is $f$ is pretty, then, give $\epsilon > 0 $, there exists $x_0 >0$ such that, for $|x| \geq  x_0, |x^2f'(x)|<\sqrt{2CD} + \epsilon$.

I have tried to visualize the problem, but I don't see why there is indeed these constants and how it can help solving the problem. I would like the logic behind this problem, for example, why of the appearance of $|x^2f'(x)|$.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1344375 (brazil undergrad MO, 2016)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in ArtofProblemSolving

Comment: But I think it should have an answer here also.